# how to create an alist with initial values

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm learning scheme (using guile) and I found the need to create an initial alist, with some keys and empty lists as their values. I was wondering what's the best practice when doing something like this. My goal is to keep this alist around so I can later add items to the lists. This is what I have now:

```
(define buckets
  `((hourly . ())
    (daily . ())
    (monthly . ())
    (yearly . ())))
```

However, this does not work when trying to `assoc-set!`, to append items to the list. This, however, works:

```
(define buckets
  (acons 'hourly '()
         (acons 'daily '()
                (acons 'monthly '()
                       (acons 'yearly '() '())))))
```

Clearly not the best looking piece of code. Is there a more idiomatic way of building such an alist? Maybe I'm doing this completely wrong. The end goal is to have these buckets that I can refer to later in different parts of code by their key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (acons 'hourly '()
         (acons 'daily '()
                (acons 'monthly '()
                       (acons 'yearly '() '()))))
$2 = ((hourly) (daily) (monthly) (yearly))
```

is the same as

```
scheme@(guile-user)> '((hourly) (daily) (monthly) (yearly))
$3 = ((hourly) (daily) (monthly) (yearly))

scheme@(guile-user)> (equal? $2 $3)
$4 = #t
```

**EDIT** `assoc-set!` doesn't work in this case because these lists are not mutable. One way to achieve a mutable list while still shortening the way to define it is to use this expression instead:

```
(map list '(hourly daily montly yearly))
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot to look at the output in the repl. Any idea why it actually looks like that? I couldn't find anything in the docs as to how the alists behave with an empty value. Any pointers on how the alists are built/what's the internal structure?

Comment: Actually, after replacing this in my code, it doesn't work :( the repl output is the same, but when trying to `assoc-set!` on the shorter version, it breaks:

`> (assoc-set! '((hourly) (daily) (monthly) (yearly)) 'hourly '(1 2 3))`
`ERROR: In procedure assoc-set!:`
`ERROR: In procedure set-cdr!: Wrong type argument in position 1 (expecting mutable pair): (hourly)`

Comment: Try `(assoc-set! (map list '(hourly daily montly yearly)) 'hourly '(1 2 3))`.

Comment: answering my own question on the internals of an alist: they're just a list of pairs `(key . value)`. In the case of `(list key)` -> creates a "pair" where its cdr is an empty list (`(key)`). That's why I can later on set the cdr to something (with `assoc-set!`) or append an element to the (empty) list.

Answer (score 0):

*My answer is in Scheme but can easily be translated to guile*

If you want an advanced solution you can take an approach which will give you an abstraction layer and easier data management once done.

Take a step into Object Modeling!

Depending on the behavior(the set of methods you will support) you'd like your object to have, it should generally look like this:

```
(define make-state-manager
      (lambda()
             (let ((data_lst '()))
                   (letrec
                        ((get-lst (lambda (key) (assoc key data_lst)))
                        ((get-data (lambda (key) (assoc-ref key data_lst)))
                        ((add-item (lam ...)
                          ... here you should have add-data , remove-data etc.
                          (action_n ....)                       
                          (dispatch (lambda (action)
                                    (cond ((eq? action ’full-list) get-lst)
                                          ((eq? action ’value) get-data)
                                          ((eq? action ’add-to-list) add-item)
                                          ...
                                          ((eq? action ’action_n) func_n)
                                          (else (error "Unknown request: ~s" action)))))
                   )
                   dispatch))
                   ))

                   ...)))
```

Usage:

```
>(define data_manager (make-state-manager))
> data_manager 
> #<procedure... >
> ((data_manager 'add-data) 'hourly '())
> ((data_manager 'value) 'hourly)
> ()
> ((data_manager 'full-list) 'hourly)
> (hourly . ())
```

Explanation:
First let creates a local state, so that you can run

```
(define data_manager1 (make-state-manager))
(define data_manager2 (make-state-manager))
```

and they will have different scopes, the actions will not affect one another.

Then in letrec you define the object methods with **your** method names.

In the dispatch (which gets dispatched :) to the user) you set the method names that the **user** will use.

sources : my brain & this crazy [book](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~mira/ppl-book-full.pdf)

if this blows your mind too hard - come back to it later...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to get away from an OO approach. I saw something in the guile docs about this, but I'm trying to use a more functional approach.